# Iterate through a directory but start from different file?

Tags: php

Is there a way to start from a different file eg. one that starts with "M" rather than with the very first file in a directory when iterating thru it (including sub-directories) with the following code?:

```
$filename = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop";
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filename, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) { ...
```

Comment: what do you mean start with?  is meaning some files have higher precedence than others and A-L should be addressed later, or do you mean skip to?

Comment: Whatever you want to achieve: No, there's no native functionality for that but you may implement your own filter when iterating over files. And there's an interesting component too: symfony/finder.

Comment: @Steve Buzonas: I'd like to skip them. My script takes very long to execute, so at least I can "pause" the script and then execute it later again from the file I last left at. Any other suggestions welcome

Comment: @matthias SPL has a number of native ways to achieve this.  The `FilterIterator`, `CallbackFilterIterator`, and `RegexIterator` just to name a few, as well as the recursive variants to those.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is a recursive iterator so you need to wrap that in a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to traverse through subdirectories.

You can then filter that with a `RegexIterator` creating a pattern to filter out those files that you don't want to begin with.

```
$filename = __DIR__;
$it = new RegexIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filename, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
    ),
    sprintf('|^%s[^A-La-l].*$|', preg_quote($filename . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '|')
);

var_dump(iterator_to_array($it));
```